# What was ReBoot's hidden message to censorship?

Tags: reboot-1994

Considered the first half-hour CGI animation series, *[ReBoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReBoot)* really gripped me back when I was a kid. Unfortunately, a lot of things were censored such as Dot being 'too sexy' to young viewers because of her breasts.

It was mentioned in a DVD special feature that the producers wrote an insult to censorship in binary code in one of the episodes.

**Does anyone know what this message said?**

[image: Image of the main characters of ReBoot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Dan commentated how the struggle was so crazy, in fact, that animators had the cityscape lights read (in binary code) "*F*** you, broadcast standards*" in one episode.
>
> <sub>["Broadcast Standards and Practices"](https://reboot.wikia.com/wiki/Broadcast_Standards_and_Practices), *ReBoot* Wikia</sub>